# How to acess nested json object with json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have parsed api request in json format with php function json_decode with this

```
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

where `$json` is my json response. I can echo page number easily with

```
echo "Page number: ".$obj->{'data'}->{'page_number'}."</br>";
```

I want to echo for example imdb code. I tried like this but nothing shows.

```
echo "IMDB Code: ".$obj->{'data'}->{'movies'}->{'imdb_code'}."</br>";
```

Here is my json response

```
{
"status":"ok",
"status_message":"Query was successful",
"data":{
   "movie_count":1,
   "limit":1,
   "page_number":1,
   "movies":[
      {
      "id":4839,
      "url":"https:\/\/yts.ag\/movie\/the-walk-2015",
      "imdb_code":"tt3488710",
      "title":"The Walk",
      "title_english":"The Walk",
      "title_long":"The Walk (2015)",
      "slug":"the-walk-2015",
      "year":2015,
      "rating":7.6,
      "runtime":123,
```

Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that json `movies` is an array, that contains several (?) Objects, not an Object itself,
so you'd need to access it like so:

```
echo "IMDB Code: ".$obj->{'data'}->{'movies'}[0]->{'imdb_code'}."</br>";
```

but there's no need to encapsulate the propertynames in `'`:

```
echo "IMDB Code: ".$obj->data->movies[0]->imdb_code."</br>";
```

Note, that this returns/echos only the *first* of the movies via index `0`.
For the other movies you'd neet to iterate through that movies-array.

Comment: This is it. Thank you very much :D

Comment: If this is the desired solution you might want to accept that answer. Glad I could help!